# How to create dynamically List and set his value

Tags: prolog

for example, if N is 2, it will create list following and set his value

```
L = [S1,S2],
L :: 1..10.
```

if N is 3 , it will crate list following and set his value

```
L = [S1,S2,S3],
L :: 1..10.
```

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for smth-like

```
list( N, List ) :-
    numlist( 1, N, List ).
```

which make

```
?- list(5, L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

Or what?

UPD:

```
kal( N, Lists ) :- govna( N, [[]], [_ | Lists] ), !.
govna( 0, Ans, Ans ).
govna( N, List, Com ) :-
    numlist( 1, 10, X ),
    append( List, [X], ListNew ),
    NewN is N - 1,
    govna( NewN, ListNew, Com ).
```

Is this it?

```
?- kal(2, X).
X = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7|...]].
```

Comment: it doesn't like that, i want to realize function like: List = [S1,S2,S3,S4], List :: 1..10.        it will create dynamically List and set his domain, I need add prefix for each item :(

Comment: Function must take an argument and make a result? What argument and result in your case is?

Comment: for example: %pass List length N ,  %create list L by length N,  %set domain L::1..10,   % pass this list to another function

Comment: Yes^_^ ,it looks like: there are three methods, 1:get N by first method, 2:i will create list and set his domin, 3: use List that create by second method for parameter of third method :)

Comment: What's mean `set domain L::1..10`?

Comment: for example, L = [S1,S2,S3],L :: 1..10.    the result is S1=1..10, S2=1..10, S3=1..10

Comment: You want predicate, that takes length N and list L as argument, and then makes a list of N lists L?

Comment: If i use directly Start=[S1,S2,S3], Start::1..10,  it work well, but i want to create dynamically Start, because it will have different count list. my method create well list, it display error when run Start::1..10,   type error in integers('S1')  , I don't know why this is integer there ........

Comment: `?- Start :: 0..100.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: Start 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: :: 0..100 .`
What it supposed to do?

Comment: Oh my god, i test this function on eclipse-clp, it works well,  if i use Amzi Prolog, it appears same problem like you ... i install many different prolog, for example: SWI-Prolog, eclispse-clp, Amzi ....

Comment: @funlive: `::` is ECLiPSe-specific. In SWI-Prolog, it's called `ins`, in SICStus `in`, and I don't think Amzi supports constraint programming at all (not sure of that, though).

Comment: Thanks @larsmans, you are right, I'am very sorry for giving many problmes to @garm0nboz1a and you are so nice :)

Answer (score 2):

To make a list of length `N`, use `length/2` with a variable as the first argument:

```
1 ?- N=4, length(List,N).
N = 4,
List = [_G487, _G490, _G493, _G496].
```